# Find all the documents in Mongodb according to distance

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I have a collection of documents on the following format:

```
{
    "type" : "car",
    "distance" : 30,
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            51.7867481, 
            -0.2016516
        ]
    }
}
```

Each document has different coordinates (which are lat/long). Now, given another document of type

```
{
    "type" : "passenger",
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            47.7867481, 
            -2.2016516
        ]
    }
}
```

what is the best way to find out all the documents of type **"car"** that are withing the distance of the document type **"passenger"**

Comment: This is identical to what you want https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/geospatial-tutorial/#searching-for-restaurants

Comment: Refer $geoNear https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/

Comment: @0.sh Thanks for the link. It is what I need, but the question is how do I convert a a point and a distance to a region programatically ?